# How do I calculate the difference between two strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Everything was  fine until when I wanted to calculate the difference between the two values and I got 0 as a result.

I'm really new to this, I'm sure it's really easy to do it and that I have to turn it from string to variable or something like that but I don't know how to do it.

```
oldx = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.left);
oldy = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.top);

newx = evt.pageX;
newy = evt.pageY;

disx=parseInt(oldx) - parseInt(newx);
disy=parseInt(oldy) - parseInt(newy);

document.getElementById('disx').innerHTML=disx;
document.getElementById('disy').innerHTML=disy;
```

I'm testing it here: http://chusmix.com/game/movechar.php You can see everything works except the end where i Get 0, 0.

How could I make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a parseInt()

```
difx=parseInt(oldx) - parseInt(newx);
  dify=parseInt(oldy) - parseInt(newy);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here

```
document.getElementById("character").style.left = evt.pageX;
document.getElementById("character").style.top = evt.pageY;

oldx = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.left);
oldy = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.top);

newx = evt.pageX;
newy = evt.pageY;

disx = parseInt(oldx) - parseInt(newx);
disy = parseInt(oldy) - parseInt(newy);
```

Here the lines

```
document.getElementById("character").style.left = evt.pageX;
document.getElementById("character").style.top = evt.pageY;
```

Overrides the original left and top style values. Please remove it and check it again.

So the script should be

```
function showCoords(evt){
    oldx = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.left);
    oldy = parseInt(document.getElementById("character").style.top);

    newx = evt.pageX;
    newy = evt.pageY;

    disx = parseInt(oldx) - parseInt(newx);
    disy = parseInt(oldy) - parseInt(newy);

    document.getElementById('oldx').innerHTML=oldx;
    document.getElementById('oldy').innerHTML=oldy;
    document.getElementById('newx').innerHTML=newx;
    document.getElementById('newy').innerHTML=newy;
    document.getElementById('disx').innerHTML=disx;
    document.getElementById('disy').innerHTML=disy;
}
```

You can find a working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5Qmcv/).

Comment: +1: very true. @Alien Segura: As I said, the problem is indeed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply a string by one to turn it to a number.

```
var myString = "5";

alert(myString + 19);    // 519
alert(myString*1 + 19);  // 24
```

Answer (score 0):

convert character to integer first and then you will be good to go

you can use this method

```
variable = parseInt(variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition operator has an overload for string and so if you add two strings holding integer values, they will be concatenated.

However, things are a little different for subtraction

```
var disx = oldx - newx;
var disy = oldy - newy;
```

The above snippet should work fine as there is no overload subtraction operator (-)  overload for string.

Example : [Click to view jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/z9eNt/)

The problem is somewhere else.